# How to implement async/await in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this function that performs some `firestore` operations and retrieve  the data.

But the problem is this returns an empty value. The reason I found was, it returns the value before fetching the data, **it doesn't wait until it retrieves the data**.

Here is my code. I have print some `print` statements to check the order of the execution.

```
getNewsOnSearchBar() {
  final String _collection = 'news';
  final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
  var newsList = [];

  print("1");
  getData() async {
    print("2");
    return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).getDocuments();
  }

  getData().then((val) async{
    if (val.documents.length > 0) {
      print("3");
      for (int i = 0; i < val.documents.length; i++) {        
        newsList.add(await val.documents[i].data["headline"]);
      }
    } else {
      print("Not Found");
    }
  });

  print("4");

  return ok;
}
```

And the output is:

```
I/flutter (17145): 1
I/flutter (17145): 2
I/flutter (17145): 4 // 4 prints before 3
I/flutter (17145): 3
```

Output I need is:

```
I/flutter (17145): 1
I/flutter (17145): 2
I/flutter (17145): 3
I/flutter (17145): 4
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your for loop is giving the problem, you have used in async and then for loop and inside the for loop you are using await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using then you can use await and that should solve your issue.
Here is how your code will look with changes and I strongly recommend to specify the type of data that your function will return.

```
getNewsOnSearchBar() async {
    final String _collection = 'news';
    final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
    var newsList = [];

    print("1");

    Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
        print("2");
        return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).getDocuments();
    }

    QuerySnapshot val = await getData();
    if (val.documents.length > 0) {
        print("3");
        for (int i = 0; i < val.documents.length; i++) {        
           newsList.add(val.documents[i].data["headline"]);
        }
    } else {
       print("Not Found");
    }
    print("4");
    return ok;
}
```

Comment: I get this error: `Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

Comment: Okay it works, but how can I return `newsList` and get it to a variable `var list = []`. When I try this, it gives the error, `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

Comment: Can you once again share the code that you are using right now? I checked the code that I commented with my firebase collection and it seems to work fine.

Comment: This is the code I am using. `final String _collection = 'news';
  final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
  var newsList = [];

  print("1");

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    print("2");
    return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).getDocuments();
  }

  QuerySnapshot val = await getData();
  if (val.documents.length > 0) {
    print("3");
    for (int i = 0; i < val.documents.length; i++) {
      newsList.add(val.documents[i].data["headline"]);
    }
  } else {
    print("Not Found");
  }
  print("4");
  return newsList;`

Comment: You will have to use await or then to do the same like var list = await getNewsOnSearchBar()

Comment: This works fine, what I want to do is to assign call this function  from some other function and take the value of `newList` to a List variable

Comment: No this doesn't work. I am calling this function from ANOTHER FUNCTION. And when I do , i get this error `'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

Comment: I think I should define a return type for `getNewsOnSearchBar()` but I don't know what

Comment: So if you check your function you need to return the newsList in your function instead of 'return ok'; and specify the return type of function as Future<List>;

Comment: Yes, I did change the `getNewsOnSearchBar()` to `Future<List> getNewsOnSearchBar()` and replaced `return ok;` with `return newList`. And when I call this function from the other function, `var returnValue = getNewsOnSearchBar()` and when I print the `returnValue`, it gives the output as `Instance of 'Future<List<dynamic>>'

Comment: since getNewsOnSearchBar() is async function, you'll have to change var returnValue = getNewsOnSearchBar() to var returnValue = await getNewsOnSearchBar() or use it as getNewsOnSearchBar().then((value){print(value);});

Comment: One question, how I can get this `value` outside of that function? I created `var list = []` and then `getNewsOnSearchBar().then((value){list = value;});` and when I try to print the `list` outside this `then(){}` it prints empty.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to wait for a value from a `Future` as in your case, don't use `then`, use `await`:

```
Future<int> myFunc() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 0);
}

void main() async {
  final int result = await myFunc();
  print(result);//0
}
```

In your case, you would like to do something similar (you may change it according to your needs):

```
getNewsOnSearchBar() async {
  final String _collection = 'news';
  final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
  var newsList = [];

  print("1");
  getData() async {
    print("2");
    return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).getDocuments();
  }

  final ref = await getData();
  if (ref.documents.length > 0) {
    print("3");
    for (int i = 0; i < ref.documents.length; i++) {
      newsList.add(await ref.documents[i].data["headline"]);
    }
  } else {
    print("Not Found");
  }

  print("4");

  return ok;
}
```

Comment: Can you change this with reference to my problem?

Comment: Thank you for this. But can you tell me how can I call this `getNewsOnSearchBar()` function from another method?  I have this issue, can you check this link? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610456/how-to-get-async-value-in-flutter`

Comment: please do not ask multiple question in one thread, I encourage you to post  a new question if you have another problem :)

Comment: Yes can you please look at this. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610456/how-to-get-async-value-in-flutter`