# How to get async value in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this function that retrieves data from `firestore` and returns a list. I and call this function from another function.

the function that retrieves data and returns the list:

```
Future<List> getNewsOnSearchBar() async{
  final String _collection = 'news';
  final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
  var newsList = [];

  print("1");

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    print("2");
    return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).getDocuments();
  }

  QuerySnapshot val = await getData();
  if (val.documents.length > 0) {
    print("3");
    for (int i = 0; i < val.documents.length; i++) {
      newsList.add(val.documents[i].data["headline"]);
    }
  } else {
    print("Not Found");
  }
  print("4");
  return newsList.toList();
}
```

And I am calling this `getNewsOnSearchBar()` function from another function that returns a `Widget` as below:

```
Widget _showSearchBar(BuildContext context) {
  var list = [];
  getNewsOnSearchBar().then((value){
    print(value); //this will print successfully
    list = value; //but this assign doesn't work
  });

  print(list); //prints an empty list

  return GFSearchBar(
    // overlaySearchListHeight: 160.0,

    searchList: list, //empty
    searchQueryBuilder: (query, list) {
      return list
          .where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    },
    overlaySearchListItemBuilder: (item) {
      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
        child: Text(
          item,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      );
    },
    onItemSelected: (item) {},
  );
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Future` in a wrong way, when you are building a widget that depends on a value from a `Future`, you need to use `FutureBuilder`,

So  for example your `_showSearchBar` method -which,I assume, you are calling inside `build` to show something on the screen- will become:

```
 Widget _showSearchBar(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getNewsOnSearchBar(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return GFSearchBar(
              // overlaySearchListHeight: 160.0,

              searchList: list, //empty
              searchQueryBuilder: (query, list) {
                return list
                    .where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                    .toList();
              },
              overlaySearchListItemBuilder: (item) {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  child: Text(
                    item,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                );
              },
              onItemSelected: (item) {},
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
      }
  );
}
```

Learn more about `Future`s and `async/await` here:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo

Comment: Now how can I assign the value to the `searchList` of the `GFSearchBar` with what I retrieve from `firestore` ?

Comment: @user13456401 you need to change your future method to return the value you want, then extract that value from the snapshot in the builder method of the FutureBuilder